# PowerPoint.Point object in PowerPoint 2007

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I made a prototype of a module in PowerPoint 2010. The module drew some lines and shape on a PowerPoint Chart. I used `PowerPoint.Point` (the Data Point of a series). According to the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.point_members%28v=office.14%29.aspx), Point Interface has the a `Point.Left`, `Point.Top`, `Point.Height` and `Point.Width` property. I used these properties to calculate the corner points of the each Point.

This worked fine in PowerPoint 2010.

But now due to some change in requirements I have to develop this in `PowerPoint 2007 SP3`. Microsoft updated the PowerPoint 2007 object model with the release of SP3 and introduced some  new objects and interfaces, such as `Chart`, `Series`, `Point` etc. But the `Point` interface does not have `Point.Left`, `Point.Top`, `Point.Height` and `Point.Width` property.

I am really stuck at the moment. Is there a way I can get these properties by some other object or some other way? Can I use some other version of `Office Interop Assembly dll`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get Top value from

```
powerpoint.DataLable.Top
```

After moving it to top with orientation property. You can do the same for the height by placing the orientation to bottom and then getting the top value. You can get the left value from

```
powerpoint.DataLable.Left
```

after moving its orientation to left. You can then calculate the right value from moving the orientation

Answer (score 0):

It isn't trivial to make a demo sample from scratch to try. But have you tried to use

```
Point.Select()
```

and then get Left, Top, Width and Height of the selection (object returned by the call or ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb251483(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb251483%28v=office.12%29.aspx))?

Comment: You can not select a Point programmatically.
While using WindowSelectionChange event, when a Point or Series is selected, the Selection.ShapeRange property only has Chart shape.